# Laravel Eloquent join with IN clause

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I'm currently trying to use the Eloquent query builder to create a join with multiple clauses, one of which being an IN clause.

The type of query I would like to create would be

```
SELECT * FROM trusts t
    LEFT JOIN trust_group tg ON tg.trust_id = t.id
        AND tg.group_id IN (1,2,4)
```

I've tried

```
->leftJoin('trust_group', function($join) {
    $join->on('trust_group.trust_id', '=', 'trusts.id');
    $join->on('trust_group.group_id', 'IN', [1,2,4]);
})
```

which results in

```
and `trust_group`.`group_id` = `IN`
```

and I've also tried

```
->leftJoin('trust_group', function($join) {
    $join->on('trust_group.trust_id', '=', 'trusts.id');
    $join->on(DB::raw('trust_group.group_id IN (1,2,4)'));
})
```

but this results in a query containing something along the lines of

```
and trust_group.group_id IN (1,2,4) = ``
```

(Obviously those group IDs are for example purposes, and would by dynamic)

Can Eloquent support IN clauses on joins?

This is only part of a pretty large query, so would prefer to use the join rather than use a `whereIn`

Comment: See [this thread](https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/4412) :|

Comment: @MihirBhende Hmm, bummer... guess it doesn't work, then! Thanks, I did Google first but didn't come across that as I wasn't searching for whereIn.

Comment: Yeah man, this case is particularly still open in laravel issues. Hope you find solution on this :)

Comment: The thread posted by Mihir Bhende suggest a workaround using raw sql, is it working for you ?

Comment: @MihirBhende : your comment could probably be posted as a legitmate answer (you would just need to be a little more talkative)

Comment: @GMB posting it as an answer now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As this is kinda deadlock at the moment, I am posting this as an answer until this is officially PRed. Unfortunately joining with an In clause is not yet supported officially. There are some discussions in this [closed thread](https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/4412)

You can use it as raw query :

```
<?php 

$results = DB::select("
            SELECT * FROM trusts t
            LEFT JOIN trust_group tg ON tg.trust_id = t.id
                AND tg.group_id IN (?)", $groupIds);
```

Also there is `Model::hydrate($array)` method if you want to have eloquent collection back from result array.

Comment: Yep, happy to sign this off as the accepted answer. Hopefully it'll be a feature eventually! Unfortunately a raw query isn't viable in this case for me, but I'll have to find a workaround!

Answer (score 1):

This is a pretty old post, but for anyone searching, you can now simply use `where` functions to build more complex joins (tested in Laravel 7) :

```php
->leftJoin('trust_group', function($join) {
    $join
        ->on('trust_group.trust_id', '=', 'trusts.id')
        ->whereIn('trust_group.group_id', [1, 2, 4])
    ;
})
```